# Walking up and down 2d slopes (pixel art)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pixel

I'm having an issue where I can't walk up slopes in unity. My art is pixel so I understand the slope is made with a gap of 1 pixel to create the actual slope, but I have no idea how to fix it so I can just walk up and down them normally. Currently, going down them makes it a little bouncy and going up them is impossible unless you jump. Any help would be appreciated! Here is what the slope looks like:
Edit: Collider looks like this but I don't know how to fix it:
[image]

Comment: What do your colliders look like for the terrain and the player trying to go up and down the slope?

Comment: I think you might need to map a smooth 2d polygon as as a collider that has the same shape as your art.

Comment: I don't really know how colliders work with a tile palette, but I did add a Tilemap Collider 2D to it.

Comment: I have updated the image to show what I believe is the collider, but I'm not sure how to fix that for just the slope sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites automatically have a polygon collider created for them when imported into the project. This polygon collider drives the tilemap polygon collider shapes.

You can modify the physics shape for a sprite to smooth it out and remove this unwanted when going up a ramp. [Custom Physics Shape documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/CustomPhysicsShape.html)

Another important thing to note in your specific problem: Often when a character has a "box-like" shape, they will get snagged on edges and small collider deviations. Unless your game's playstyle is based around a box-shaped entity and interactions, it's usually recommended to use a rounded collider for the moving characters (like a 2d or 3d capsule collider).

Comment: You have saved me so much pain! Thank you for the help and the new found knowledge!